# No Damage in Unity Survival Shooter Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been following the Shooter Survival tutorial offered by Unity. I have been using it to understand how certain bits of code interact with and call upon each other in different scripts in c#. Recently I have run into a problem where I take no damage from the enemy attacks; I can still harm them.

My code for the Player Health

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

namespace CompleteProject
{
public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{

public int startingHealth = 100;                            // The amount of health the player starts the game with.
    public int currentHealth;                                   // The current health the player has.
    public Slider healthSlider;                                 // Reference to the UI's health bar.
    public Image damageImage;                                   // Reference to an image to flash on the screen on being hurt.
    public AudioClip deathClip;                                 // The audio clip to play when the player dies.
    public float flashSpeed = 5f;                               // The speed the damageImage will fade at.
    public Color flashColour = new Color(1f, 0f, 0f, 0.1f);     // The colour the damageImage is set to, to flash.

    Animator anim;                                              // Reference to the Animator component.
    AudioSource playerAudio;                                    // Reference to the AudioSource component.
    PlayerMovement playerMovement;                              // Reference to the player's movement.
    PlayerShooting playerShooting;                              // Reference to the PlayerShooting script.
    bool isDead;                                                // Whether the player is dead.
    bool damaged;                                               // True when the player gets damaged.


    void Awake ()

    {
        // Setting up the references.
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
        playerAudio = GetComponent <AudioSource> ();
        playerMovement = GetComponent <PlayerMovement> ();
        playerShooting = GetComponentInChildren <PlayerShooting> ();

        // Set the initial health of the player.
        currentHealth = startingHealth;
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // If the player has just been damaged...
        if(damaged)
        {
            // ... set the colour of the damageImage to the flash colour.
            damageImage.color = flashColour;
        }
        // Otherwise...
        else
        {
            // ... transition the colour back to clear.
            damageImage.color = Color.Lerp (damageImage.color, Color.clear, flashSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Reset the damaged flag.
        damaged = false;
    }


    public void TakeDamage (int amount)
    {
        // Set the damaged flag so the screen will flash.
        damaged = true;

        // Reduce the current health by the damage amount.
        currentHealth -= amount;

        // Set the health bar's value to the current health.
        healthSlider.value = currentHealth;

        // Play the hurt sound effect.
        playerAudio.Play ();

        // If the player has lost all it's health and the death flag hasn't been set yet...
        if(currentHealth <= 0 && !isDead)
        {
            // ... it should die.
            Death ();
        }
    }


    void Death ()
    {
        // Set the death flag so this function won't be called again.
        isDead = true;

        // Turn off any remaining shooting effects.
        playerShooting.DisableEffects ();

        // Tell the animator that the player is dead.
        anim.SetTrigger ("Die");

        // Set the audiosource to play the death clip and play it (this will stop the hurt sound from playing).
        playerAudio.clip = deathClip;
        playerAudio.Play ();

        // Turn off the movement and shooting scripts.
        playerMovement.enabled = false;
        playerShooting.enabled = false;
    }


    public void RestartLevel ()
    {
        // Reload the level that is currently loaded.
        SceneManager.LoadScene (0);
    }
}
}
```

My code for the Enemy Attack

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace CompleteProject
{
public class EnemyAttack : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float timeBetweenAttacks = 0.5f;     // The time in seconds between each attack.
    public int attackDamage = 10;               // The amount of health taken away per attack.


    Animator anim;                              // Reference to the animator component.
    GameObject player;                          // Reference to the player GameObject.
    PlayerHealth playerHealth;                  // Reference to the player's health.
    EnemyHealth enemyHealth;                    // Reference to this enemy's health.
    bool playerInRange;                         // Whether player is within the trigger collider and can be attacked.
    float timer;                                // Timer for counting up to the next attack.


    void Awake ()
    {
        // Setting up the references.
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player");
        playerHealth = player.GetComponent <PlayerHealth> ();
        enemyHealth = GetComponent<EnemyHealth>();
        anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
    }


    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        // If the entering collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is in range.
            playerInRange = true;
        }
    }


    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        // If the exiting collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is no longer in range.
            playerInRange = false;
        }
    }


    void Update ()
    {
        // Add the time since Update was last called to the timer.
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        // If the timer exceeds the time between attacks, the player is in range and this enemy is alive...
        if(timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange && enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        {
            // ... attack.
            Attack ();
        }

        // If the player has zero or less health...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0)
        {
            // ... tell the animator the player is dead.
            anim.SetTrigger ("PlayerDead");
        }
    }


    void Attack ()
    {
        // Reset the timer.
        timer = 0f;

        // If the player has health to lose...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth > 0)
        {
            // ... damage the player.
            playerHealth.TakeDamage (attackDamage);
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have been told from a friend of mine that uses C++ that he finds it odd that in the Player hierarchy the Player Health is an asset and might have to be directly called upon somehow.

[Screen shot of Player hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IxjV.jpg)

Comment: PlayerHealth is not an asset, it's a component on your player object. When you pause the game, can you see in the inspector for the EnemyAttack script that the player && playerHealth are correctly populated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the code works as you have provided it, but requires a specific set of circumstances for `EnemyAttack` to successfully call `PlayerHealth.TakeDamage()`:

- The GameObject your `EnemyAttack` is attached to needs a `Rigidbody`, you may want to set *IsKinematic = true*
- Any type of `Collider` component - *flagged with **IsTrigger = true***
- The GameObject your `PlayerHealth` is attached to needs both a `Rigidbody` and `Collider` with the Gameobject's Tag set to 'Player', as you've proven in the screencap you provided

I believe your `EnemyAttack` is failing to damage the player because the flag `playerInRange` is always false. This flag is set to true when passing through `OnTriggerEnter()` but not before `OnTriggerExit()`. Since the components aren't set up properly in the scene, `OnTriggerEnter()` will never be called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely here:

```
if(timer >= timeBetweenAttacks && playerInRange && enemyHealth.currentHealth > 0)
  {
   // ... attack.
   Attack ();
  }
```

For the player to be attacked by the Enemy three things have to be true at th-same time.
`timer` has to **more than** or equals to **0.5f**. `playerInRange` must also be `true`. Finally `enemyHealth.currentHealth` must be more than **0**.

Once your code is over **30** lines with too many C# scripts, you **must** know how to **debug** your own code.

My best guess is that `playerInRange` is never `true` and that's why attack is **not** being called. Add `Debug.Log("Attacked Player");` before `Attack ();` and check if "**Attacked Player**" is shown when Enemy attacks player. If it is not then one of these is `false`.

Also add `Debug.Log("Player is in Range");` to see if player is being detected at-all in the 
`void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other);` function like below:

```
   void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        // If the entering collider is the player...
        if(other.gameObject == player)
        {
            // ... the player is in range.
            playerInRange = true;
            Debug.Log("Player is in Range");
        }
    }
```

These will tell you what is going on in your scene.